# PyGame border collision detection not working

Tags: python, pygame

I am new to pygame and I made a screen border detection but it doesn't work

```py
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([854, 480])
```

and to check if its touching the edge

```py
pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if playerY > 0:
    if pressed[pygame.K_w]: playerY -= 1
if playerY > 854:
    if pressed[pygame.K_s]: playerY += 1
if playerX > 0:
    if pressed[pygame.K_a]: playerX -= 1
if playerX > 480:
    if pressed[pygame.K_d]: playerX += 1
```

but if we use it breaks / the player gets stuck

and the entire code is

```py
import pygame

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([854, 480])

running = True

playerX = 70
playerY = 400

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if playerY > 0:
        if pressed[pygame.K_w]: playerY -= 1
    if playerY > 854:
        if pressed[pygame.K_s]: playerY += 1
    if playerX > 0:
        if pressed[pygame.K_a]: playerX -= 1
    if playerX > 480:
        if pressed[pygame.K_d]: playerX += 1
    
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))

    player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), pygame.Rect(playerX, playerY, 10, 25))

    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Does `playerY < 854` and `playerX < 480` help?

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh nope It gets stuck on 70% to theright and the ground collision doesn't work

Comment: I'd like to help, could you offer a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) by editing your post?

Comment: You have swapped 854 and 480. the width is 854 and the height is 480. Hence `playerY < 480` and `playerX < 854`.

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh k wait

Comment: @Rabbid76 you broke it, even more, we can't even move to the right or down just up and left

Comment: @Ynjxsjmh I added my code in it

Comment: @ARandomPro In `pygame.display.set_mode([854, 480])`, the max value of X is 854, the max value of Y is 480. @Rabbid76 is right.

Comment: @Rabbid76 but i cant move right or down after adding that code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The width of the window is 854 and the height is 480.You have to test if `playerY < 480` and `playerX < 854`. Additionally you should consider the size of the player:

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([854, 480])
running = True
playerX = 70
playerY = 400

while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    if playerY > 0:
        if pressed[pygame.K_w]: playerY -= 1
    if playerY < 480 - 25:
        if pressed[pygame.K_s]: playerY += 1
    if playerX > 0:
        if pressed[pygame.K_a]: playerX -= 1
    if playerX < 854 - 10:
        if pressed[pygame.K_d]: playerX += 1
    
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), pygame.Rect(playerX, playerY, 10, 25))
    pygame.display.flip()
```

---

I suggest simplifying the code with [`move_ip`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.move_ip) and [`clamp_ip`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.clamp_ip):

```py
import pygame
pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode([854, 480])
player = pygame.Rect(70, 40, 10, 25)

running = True
while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False

    pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()
    player.move_ip(
        pressed[pygame.K_d] - pressed[pygame.K_a],
        pressed[pygame.K_s] - pressed[pygame.K_w]
    )
    player.clamp_ip(screen.get_rect())    
    
    screen.fill((255, 255, 255))
    player = pygame.draw.rect(screen, (0, 0, 0), player)
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Thanks! it fixed it time to add gravity to my game Bye!

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```
pressed = pygame.key.get_pressed()

if playerY > 0:
    if pressed[pygame.K_w]: playerY -= 1
if playerY < 480:
    if pressed[pygame.K_s]: playerY += 1
if playerX > 0:
    if pressed[pygame.K_a]: playerX -= 1
if playerX < 854:
    if pressed[pygame.K_d]: playerX += 1
```

Edit: [@rabbid76](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5577765/rabbid76) was right! You have swapped your x and y!

Comment: It gets stuck on 70% to the right and the ground collision doesn't work